# MySQL - Trying to get minimum value for each day

Tags: mysql

Got a table that holds dates and values, looks like this:

```
...Date........Value
2016-10-01      2.3
2016-10-01      1.6
2016-10-01      7.0
2016-10-02      2.4
2016-10-02      1.9
2016-10-02      7.3
```

etc, so multiple dates with multiple values for each date.

I can't figure out how to write the SQL to get to return a single row with the minimum value for each day.

Tried this but get error:Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'm.seldate' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT DISTINCT seldate 
           FROM mytable s
           LEFT 
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT MIN(myval) minval 
                  FROM mytable 
                 GROUP 
                    BY seldate
              ) m
             ON s.seldate = m.seldate
```

Comment: This question is asked and answered endlessly on SO. Sometimes, some of those answers are correct. See the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: that link to the manual show unique article id's, my table doesn't have that ... got a link to a correct answer?

Comment: I can only suggest that you try again.

Comment: try what again?

Comment: my apologies, I realised what you mean, retried and it seems to have worked .. thank you.

Comment: SO welcomes contributors to answer their own questions. So, feel free to do so, or delete, as is your prerogative. However, note that the question you're answering is likely to be different from the one that was asked!

Comment: To get the `description`, too, you need [_Groupwise Max_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/)

Answer (score 1):

The following will return the minimum myvalue and the corresponding 'description' column (which I omitted in the original post) for each unique value of seldate within the table:

```
SELECT seldate, description, myvalue
FROM   selections s1
WHERE  myvalue=(SELECT min(s2.myvalue)
              FROM selections s2
              WHERE s1.seldate = s2.seldate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select seldate, min(myval) as minval 
from mytable 
group by seldate
```

Comment: thanks ... if there were extra columns in the table e.g. 'Description' for each row, how would I return the description and the date with the lowest value? Thanks

Comment: As before - select seldate, description, min(myval) as minval from mytable group by seldate, description